# Add a singleton service from its type?

Tags: c#

I have a lot of handler classes and need to automatically add them all as singletons on start-up.

But it seems to be trying to add the interface?

```
var handlerType = typeof(IEventHandler);

var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => handlerType.IsAssignableFrom(p));

foreach (var type in types)
{
    serviceCollection.AddSingleton(type);
}
```

Comment: `IEventHandler` is assignable to `IEventHandler` so I'd expect that to happen. Perhaps exclude interfaces and abstract classes here?

Comment: The interface itself *is* a type and is assignable from itself.  Maybe you want to include `&& !handlerType.IsInterface` in your `.Where`?

Answer (score 0):

For archive that filter only classes:

```
.Where(p => handlerType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass);
```